# Are hairline cracks in a stud a problem

Tags: framing

So related to my question [Do the nails stick out at all when toe-nailing studs?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/84064/do-the-nails-stick-out-any-when-toe-nailing-studs), is it a problem if the studs develop hairline cracks from the nailing?  It seems like almost every nail splits the board ever so slightly.

[image: Front]

[image: Back]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it's not a problem. It's almost unavoidable with dry lumber, and it doesn't appreciably weaken the wall.

If it really bothers you, shoot one nail into each narrow edge of the stud up about 6 inches. This will tie the grain together tightly... probably making the stud stronger than it was originally.

Comment: Agreed. The splitting is also parallel to the loading.

Answer (score 3):

You can also blunt the head of the nail to prevent splitting, it sounds counter intuitive, forcing it into the wood but blunting allows it to cut  into the wood vs. a sharp tip wedges its way through. To blunt, simply place the nail head on some concrete and tap the nail tip- no need to wack it, simple tap will do.

Comment: +1 for this tip. Give each nail a quick tap with the hammer before driving it.